# Stop XHR request in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, execution

Is it possible to stop the request/response timeout of the following code when I refresh the page?

```
    setInterval(function(){
    var xhr = $.ajax({
    url:'/ajax_controller/searchForTracks/'+logged_user_id,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data+' tracks added');
            }
        });
    },5000);
```

I have tried:

```
    $(window).unload(function(){
            xhr.abort();
        });
```

and

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      throw new error('Aborting javascript');
   }
```

but nothings works for me. I just want to refresh the page instantly and not to wait until the xhr request is finished on my URL ( as it takes up to a few minutes sometimes );

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error in your console? It looks like it may throw an `xhr` not defined error.

Comment: No. I don't get any error. I only get when using the throw new error..to abort javascript; But it still waits for the current XHR on the  /ajax_controller/searchForTracks/ to finish. I need to abort the current waiting on that and just refresh instantly.

Comment: Per the `$.ajax` documentation it returns a `XMLHttpRequest`, which supports a `.abort()` method, which is described as exactly what you want.  When you place a breakpoint in your `$(window).unload` function, does it step into it and have the `xhr` populated properly?

Comment: $(window).unload(function(){ console.log(xhr); xhr.abort(); });  <~ Whats the console say?

Comment: I will send you the response of the console.log in 2-3 mins. I have to wait for the script to finish loading :)

Comment: If `xhr.abort();` doesn't throw an error, then it must abort *an* xhr object, but it can't possibly be the one established in the setTimeout fn. Why? Because the latter is localized with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var xhr = $.ajax({...   <---
},5000);
```

You're initializing the variable INSIDE the callback function, all you have to do is:

```
var xhr;
setInterval(function(){
    xhr = $.ajax({...
},5000);
```

and then you can do

```
console.log(xhr); // Object...
```

also I'd suggest caching the setInterval so you can do

```
var myInterval =     setInterval(function(){
        xhr = $.ajax({...
    },5000);
```

and if you need to cancel the interval, just do

```
clearTimeout(myInterval);
```

TLDR: it's a scope issue.